# If statement with two conditions and NA

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

[image: snapshot]

I am looking to use a conditional statement to access date rows which are **before 0021-01-11** and **have NA value** in a specific column (People_vaccinated for example). For those rows I wanted to impute with zero.

I want to use an IF statement with (condition1 AND condition 2).
Condition1 can be `df$People_vaccinated == NA` and condition2 can be `df$date < 'given date'`

Comment: You cannot compare with `NA` using `==`. You need to use `is.na` to check for `NA` values.

Comment: Thank you! Would you use something like this:

if(is.na(df$People_vaccinated)) & (df$date < '0021-01-12')) <- 0

Comment: 1.As in the guidelines for SO/R, please do not post images of data but use code to present the data. 2.You can use `dataset$newcol <- ifelse(is.na(dataset$var1) & dataset$var2 < CRITERIA)` to impute a new column the vectorized way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help -

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c('0021-01-07', '0021-01-08','0021-01-11', '0021-01-12'),
                 a = c(2, NA, 3, NA), 
                 b = c(1, NA, 2, 3))

ind <- match('0021-01-11', df$Date)

df$a[1:ind][is.na(df$a[1:ind])] <- 0
df

#        Date  a  b
#1 0021-01-07  2  1
#2 0021-01-08  0 NA
#3 0021-01-11  3  2
#4 0021-01-12 NA  3
```

Or using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
       mutate(a = replace(a, 
              row_number() <= match('0021-01-11', Date) & is.na(a), 0))
df
```